# The good way to set classpath for Spark YARN cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark-Cassandra connector application, the config part of the code are:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("Some Name")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
    .set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/absolute_path_to/my.jar")
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://127.0.0.1:7077", "App", conf)
```

And I submit with:

```
spark-submit --class com.data.MyApp --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
--executor-cores 2 --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 4G \
--jars /absolute_path_to/my.jar ./target/scala-2.10/ds-spark-assembly-1.0.jar
```

I CAN make it work. But can I use "relative path" in my code for `spark.executor.extraClassPath`? If I can, the path is relative to where in all cluster nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I make it work as:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("Some Name")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
    .setJars(Seq("my.jar"))
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://127.0.0.1:7077", "App", conf)
```

And I don't need to put `--jar` option in `spark-submit`.